# I don't know how to get orders from the terminal in a multithread situation

Tags: c, multithreading, ubuntu, terminal, pthreads

I am working on an UDP Socket project. I use 2 threads in my client program. The first thread registers and maintain connexion with the server. The second thread needs to answer some orders from the terminal, for example sending the configuration of the client to the server.
I would need to be able to type onto the terminal when the program is running to inform the second thread of what it needs to do but I don't know how to implement it in my code, and I don't even know what to look for on google.

I haven't tried anything since I have absolutely no idea how to do this

I would like to be able to type "sendconf" for example in the terminal while the program is running and have the second thread answering to that. I know how to send the configuration of the client to the server, I just don't know how to inform the thread it needs to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Message queues?

Add a "message" (the command) to a queue that the second thread polls, it then processes the message and sends a reply to another queue which is polled by the first thread.

If you want to be synchronous instead, the second thread can instead set data directly in the message structure for the reply, and then set a flag that it's finished. The first thread keeps waiting on the flag and then gives the result to the user.